# Express Session not persisting across routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, express-session

I am trying to save a user id variable to a cookie to use in my OAuth2 flow but I am having some issues accessing that cookie value from a different route. Here is my code:

In my app.js:

```
var router = require("./routes/index");

app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: "secret key",
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000
    }
}));

app.use(router, session);
```

In my router.js where all the routes are, I have a '/auth' route where I set the cookie like this:

```
req.session.sender_id = 'my cookie value';
```

Now in the router.js file I try to access that same cookie from my `/callback` route like this:

```
console.log("cookie session: " + req.session.sender_id);
```

But I always get `undefined` for the cookie. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

### EDIT:

Adding more of my router code. Here is my /auth route where I am setting the cookie:

```
router.post("/action", function(req, res) {

    var action = req.body.queryResult.parameters.action;

    //-----AUTHENTICATION
    if (action == "auth") {
        res.set({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        //set the user id cookie
        req.session.sender_id = req.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.sender.id;
        console.log("cookie session: " + req.session.id);
        console.log("cookie session: " + req.session.sender_id);

        authenticate(req.body).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
        });

    ...
```

The authenticate function which is called basically just adds a user to mongo db or updates if already exists - it does not interact with the session. And here is my /callback route where I am trying to read the session:

```
router.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

    console.log("cookie session: " + req.session.id);
    console.log("sender_id: " + JSON.stringify(req.session));

...
```

Comment: Can you include the more of the router.js code? What route are you in when it says undefined and how is the route set up?

Comment: @ViktorH I've added more of my router code. I am in the /callback route when it says undefined. I checked the id of the session and it is different in the /action route than in the /callback route...this is why it is undefined but how can I make the session persist?

Comment: Have you tried `resave: false` and removing `saveUninitialized`? Also, in your callback route you're inspecting `JSON.stringify(req.session)`, which may not give an accurate representation of the data. What if you log `req.session.sender_id` instead? Also, is there just the one process running so the memory store will work? If not, you'll need to persist somewhere.